# Omnifaces Components#includeCompositeComponent set attribute value

Tags: jsf-2, composite-component, omnifaces

When dynamically creating a composite component with Omniface's [`Components #includeCompositeComponent`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/utils/Components), is it possible to pass attributes values (such as attribute `myValue`) so that it is available for a pre-render event on the composite?

```
<composite:interface>
     <composite:attribute name="myValue" required="true" />
</composite:interface>
<composite:implementation>
    <!-- this works! -->
    <h:outputText value="#{cc.attrs.myValue}" />
    <!-- this doesn't execute -->
    <f:event id="eventId" 
             type="javax.faces.event.PreRenderComponentEvent" 
             listener="#{bean.someAction(cc.attrs.myValue)}" />
    <!-- stuff -->
</composite:implementation>
```

However, I'm able to access `myValue` on the xhtml (via `#{cc.attrs.myValue}`), but its not available for pre-render (I used [`UIComponent#getAttributes`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#getAttributes()) to specify `myValue`'s value).

**Edit:** if the attribute is also available in `@PostConstruct` (via managed-property) it would also do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [javadoc](http://omnifaces.org/docs/javadoc/1.8/org/omnifaces/util/Components.html#includeCompositeComponent(javax.faces.component.UIComponent,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)):

> `public static UIComponent includeCompositeComponent(UIComponent parent, String libraryName, String resourceName, String id)`
>
> ...
>
> **Returns:**
> The created composite component, which can if necessary be further used to set custom attributes or value expressions on it.

So, just get hold of the returned `UIComponent` instance and make use of [`UIComponent#getAttributes()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#getAttributes()) to put static values or [`UIComponent#setValueExpression()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#setValueExpression(java.lang.String,%20javax.el.ValueExpression)) to set EL expressions.

```
UIComponent composite = Components.includeCompositeComponent(parent, library, name, id);
composite.getAttributes().put("myValue", myStaticValue);
// Or:
composite.setValueExpression("myValue", Components.createValueExpression("#{bean.myValue}", String.class));
// ...
```

Comment: Does the `setValueExpression` binds the composite attribute with the value in the bean (`bean.myValue`)? Nevertheless, going to try it. Thank you

Comment: It has exactly the same effect as `<my:composite myValue="#{bean.myValue}">` whereas the `getAttribute()` approach has exactly the same effect as `<my:composite myValue="myStaticValue">` provided that it's just a `String`.

Comment: After a closer read, I guess the `setValueExpression` just gets the value from another bean. Am I right?

Comment: Nope, it basically sets the EL expression. The getter/setter behind it will only be called when needed, exactly like when you declare it "the usual way".

Comment: Got it - the `getAttribute` approach is enough - Now, I'm trying to user a `PreRenderComponentEvent` in order to pass `myValue` to some logic in the composite's backing bean (`#{bean.someAction(cc.attrs.myValue)}`), but the event doesn't fire. Is it due to page construction moments? Is it already too late to use events?